# What is the reason for a daily maxium reputation?

Tags: discussion

I was surprised, not to find this asked already here or explained in the help section - but maybe I'm the one who just didn't find it...

So, what is the reason for establishing the daily maximum reputation?

I could imagine, it's due to abusing it by artificially voting up questions from dummy accounts - is it that?

Because at least one thing is unfair in this regard, if I answer a question in a very well regarded way, why should it be different, if 40 people vote for me on the first day instead of doing so in two days?

Comment: To level the playingfield and to remind people to take a break from time to time. Without the rep cap, Jon Skeet would reap the benefit of 30,000 answers without ever having to add a new one ever again and no-one could catch up with him.

Comment: See [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447)

Comment: I'd argue that between an answer receiving 40 upvotes in a single day and an answer receiving 1 upvote on 40 separate days, the latter is likely a more useful answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the link, yep, could have thought of looking in the general meta...

Comment: Mostly? So people will know when to stop for the day...